# Fred's parents? Candy? Magic?

Tags: plot-explanation, hop

In the movie *Hop* how aware are Fred's parents of any of the "magical forces" within the film.

They treat him like a slacker throughout the entire movie. Then at the end, his dad thinks he's gone completely insane, and he refuses to believe that Fred is the new Easter Bunny... until he sees the sleigh being pulled by the chicks.

But, they must have believed to some extent. Otherwise, how would they explain all of the candy Fred and his sister received on Easter while they were growing up?

Fred even kept the golden rabbit from years ago.

Answer (score 1):

When I was growing up, the children in my town used to find presents outside their houses on Christmas day (I later found that the head of the local Rotary Association had been leaving them).

Now, leaving aside the question of why they did this, I'm pleased to report that because my parents aren't mental, at no point did they imagine that Santa actually exists and visited my town once a year.

By the same token, merely finding a basket of chocolate isn't likely to tip his parents off that magical bunnies are real, hence their surprise at the end of the film.